# What is the difference between require_relative and require in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, require

What is the difference between `require_relative` and `require` in Ruby?

Comment: Before 1.9.2 there was no need for require_relative, because current directory of script was in `$:`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/

Comment: require_relative requires a file specifically pointed to relative to the file that calls it. require requires a file included in the $LOAD_PATH.

Answer (score 323, accepted):

Just look at the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html):

> `require_relative` complements the builtin method `require` by allowing you to load a file that is relative to the file containing the `require_relative` statement.
>
> For example, if you have unit test classes in the "test" directory, and data for them under the test "test/data" directory, then you might use a line like this in a test case:
>
> ```
> require_relative "data/customer_data_1"
> ```

Comment: Is there a difference between `require './file.rb'` and `require_relative 'file.rb'`?

Comment: @CiroSantilli Yes. `require_relative` allows you to "load a file that is **relative to the file containing the `require_relative` statement**". With `require`, `./` indicates a path that is relative to your current working directory.

Comment: I think it's more important to note that `require str` will always search through directories in $LOAD_PATH. You should use `require_relative` when the file you need to load exists somewhere relative to the file that calls for the loading. Reserve `require` for "external" dependencies.

Answer (score 116):

**`require_relative` is a convenient subset of `require`**

```
require_relative('path')
```

equals:

```
require(File.expand_path('path', File.dirname(__FILE__)))
```

if `__FILE__` is defined, or it raises `LoadError` otherwise.

This implies that:

- `require_relative 'a'` and `require_relative './a'` require relative to the **current file** (`__FILE__`).

  This is what you want to use when requiring inside your library, since you don't want the result to depend on the current directory of the caller.
- `eval('require_relative("a.rb")')` raises `LoadError` because `__FILE__` is not defined inside `eval`.

  This is why you can't use `require_relative` in RSpec tests, which get `eval`ed.

The following operations are only possible with `require`:

- `require './a.rb'` requires relative to the **current directory**
- `require 'a.rb'` uses the search path (`$LOAD_PATH`) to require. It does not find files relative to current directory or path.

  This is not possible with `require_relative` because the docs say that path search only happens when "the filename does not resolve to an absolute path" (i.e. starts with `/` or `./` or `../`), which is always the case for `File.expand_path`.

The following operation is possible with both, but you will want to use `require` as it is shorter and more efficient:

- `require '/a.rb'` and `require_relative '/a.rb'` both require the absolute path.

**Reading the source**

When the docs are not clear, I recommend that you take a look at the sources (toggle source in the docs). In some cases, it helps to understand what is going on.

require:

```
VALUE rb_f_require(VALUE obj, VALUE fname) {
  return rb_require_safe(fname, rb_safe_level());
}
```

require_relative:

```
VALUE rb_f_require_relative(VALUE obj, VALUE fname) {
    VALUE base = rb_current_realfilepath();
    if (NIL_P(base)) {
        rb_loaderror("cannot infer basepath");
    }
    base = rb_file_dirname(base);
    return rb_require_safe(rb_file_absolute_path(fname, base), rb_safe_level());
}
```

This allows us to conclude that

```
require_relative('path')
```

is the same as:

```
require(File.expand_path('path', File.dirname(__FILE__)))
```

because:

```
rb_file_absolute_path   =~ File.expand_path
rb_file_dirname1        =~ File.dirname
rb_current_realfilepath =~ __FILE__
```

Answer (score 88):

### Summary

#### Use `require` for installed gems

#### Use `require_relative` for local files

`require` uses your **`$LOAD_PATH`** to find the files.
`require_relative` uses the current location of the file using the statement

---

#### require

Require relies on you having installed (e.g. `gem install [package]`) a package somewhere on your system for that functionality.

When using `require` you *can* use the "`./`" format  for a file in the current directory, e.g. `require "./my_file"` but that is not a common or recommended practice and you should use `require_relative` instead.

#### require_relative

This simply means include the file 'relative to the location of the file with the require_relative statement'.  I *generally* recommend that files should be "within" the current directory tree as opposed to "up", e.g. **don't** use

```
require_relative '../../../filename'
```

(up 3 directory levels) within the file system because that tends to create unnecessary and brittle dependencies.  However in some cases if you are already 'deep' within a directory tree then "up and down" another directory tree branch may be necessary.  More simply perhaps, **don't use require_relative for files outside of this repository** (assuming you are using git which is largely a de-facto standard at this point, late 2018).

Note that `require_relative` uses the current directory *of the file with the require_relative* statement (so not necessarily your current directory that you are using the command from).  This keeps the `require_relative` path "stable" as it always be relative to the file requiring it in the same way.

Comment: great simple explanation!

Answer (score 77):

**From Ruby API**:

> require_relative complements the
>   builtin method require by allowing you
>   to load a file that is relative to the
>   file containing the require_relative
>   statement.
>
> When you use require to load a file,
>   you are usually accessing
>   functionality that has been properly
>   installed, and made accessible, in
>   your system. require does not offer a
>   good solution for loading files within
>   the project’s code. This may be useful
>   during a development phase, for
>   accessing test data, or even for
>   accessing files that are "locked" away
>   inside a project, not intended for
>   outside use.
>
> For example, if you have unit test
>   classes in the "test" directory, and
>   data for them under the test
>   "test/data" directory, then you might
>   use a line like this in a test case:
>
> ```
> require_relative "data/customer_data_1"
> ```
>
> Since neither
>   "test" nor "test/data" are likely to
>   be in Ruby’s library path (and for
>   good reason), a normal require won’t
>   find them. require_relative is a good
>   solution for this particular problem.
>
> You may include or omit the extension
>   (.rb or .so) of the file you are
>   loading.
>
> path must respond to to_str.

You can find the documentation at http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html

Answer (score 48):

The top answers are correct, but deeply technical.  For those newer to  Ruby:

- `require_relative` will most likely be used to bring in code from another file that you wrote.

for example, what if you have data in `~/my-project/data.rb` and you want to include that in `~/my-project/solution.rb`?  in `solution.rb` you would add `require_relative 'data'`.

it is important to note these files do not need to be in the same directory.  `require_relative '../../folder1/folder2/data'` is also valid.

- `require` will most likely be used to bring in code from a library someone else wrote.

for example, what if you want to use one of the helper functions provided in the `active_support` library?  you'll need to install the gem with `gem install activesupport` and then in the file `require 'active_support'`.

```
require 'active_support/all'
"FooBar".underscore
```

---

Said differently--

- `require_relative` requires a file specifically pointed to relative to the file that calls it.
- `require` requires a file included in the `$LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: How can I up vote this answer and bring it all the way to the top, so every visitor of this question page will get a clear and understandable answer right away without breaking their brains?

Comment: This answer needs to top of all :)

Answer (score 16):

I just saw the RSpec's code has some comment on `require_relative` being O(1) constant and `require` being O(N) linear. So probably the difference is that `require_relative` is the preferred one than `require`.

Comment: Interesting. I landed here looking for info on a speed comparison. My thinking was that `require_relative` was faster because the loader doesn't have to traverse the load path in search of the file. Essentially, `require_relative` provides a direct link.

Comment: Early disscussion about [require_relative speed](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2990962) and the RSpec [changelog](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/Changelog.md#280rc2--2011-12-19).

Answer (score 1):

I want to add that when using Windows you can use `require './1.rb'` if the script is run local or from a mapped network drive but when run from an UNC `\\servername\sharename\folder` path you need to use `require_relative './1.rb'`.

I don't mingle in the discussion which to use for other reasons.

Comment: I wanted to know how do you load the `require_relative` file

Could you please throw an idea at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487784/appiumruby-load-error-in-the-gem

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, both `require` and `require_relative` are used to load external files or libraries into your Ruby program. However, they have a slight difference in terms of how they locate and load the files.

1. `require`:

- `require` is used to load files that are part of Ruby's load path or are installed as gems.
- It searches for the specified file in the directories listed in the `$LOAD_PATH` global variable.
- You need to provide the absolute or relative path of the file from one of the load path directories.
- Example: `require 'my_file'`

2. `require_relative`:

- `require_relative` is used to load files that are relative to the current file's directory.
- It does not search in the Ruby load path or gems, but only looks for the file in relation to the current file.
- You need to provide the relative path of the file from the current file's directory.
- Example: require_relative `'subdirectory/my_file'`