# Ruby require 'file' doesn't work but require './file' does. Why?

Tags: ruby, require

I have a folder full of ruby files, and when I try and require one file in another that is in the same directory using `require 'file'` I get a `LoadError` but when I use `require './file'` everything works fine. Can somebody explain to me why this happens and if there is any way I can require a file without adding a `./` onto the file?

(Picture of directory):
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between require\_relative and require in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-the-difference-between-require-relative-and-require-in-ruby)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to `require` a file not from the system `$LOAD_PATH` but rather relative to the directory of the file you are `require`ing *from*, you should use [`require_relative`](http://RubyDoc.Info/docs/ruby-core/1.9.2/Kernel:require_relative). (Which, as you can see, isn't exactly *extensively* documented.)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have current directory in your loadpath.

Check the contents of the $LOAD_PATH variable

Answer (score 0):

Though it is very old post I think some extra information will be very useful to beginner.

The best way to think of require is in relation to the UNIX $PATH variable. Just by way of a refresher, the $PATH variable in UNIX is a list of directories where executables can be found. So when you type the name of a program on any UNIX terminal, your computer is looking through the executable files in the directories specified in your $PATH variable. require does something very similar. When, for example, you write require 'set' at the top of your Ruby file, you are telling Ruby to look through a bunch of directories for a library called set.rb (Ruby's set library).

So where does Ruby look for set.rb? Well, once again, Ruby has something very similar to UNIX's $PATH variable. It is the global variable $LOAD_PATH also sometimes known by it's ugly and undescriptive alias $: (which I don't suggest using by the way--short though it may be). It is an array of directory names where Ruby looks when it comes across a require.

There is nice informative post [here](https://github.com/ericmathison/articles/blob/master/understaning-require-in-ruby.md) where you can get more information about `require`, `load` and `require_relative`