# require 'command_line_argument_parser'?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm following a tutorial here for a simple web crawler (http://www.skorks.com/2009/07/how-to-write-a-web-crawler-in-ruby/) and one of the lines is to `require 'command_line_argument_parser'`.

My system is unable to find the gem. The post was written in 2009. Without the gem, the code I downloaded from this guy doesn't work.

Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

If the main point of the code is Web crawling, the cli arg parser can probably be switched out without upsetting much. I would just use Ruby's build-in `optparse` library. http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html

Answer (score 0):

I found `command_line_argument_parser` in the [ZIP archive](http://www.skorks.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/web-crawler.zip) for the tutorial. If you've extracted the file into the same directory as your crawler and it still doesn't work, try changing the require line to [`require_relative`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-require-relative-in-ruby).

I'd also recommend switching to optparse if you have the time though, it's much more robust.