# Ruby-require throwing up error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to load rubywrite and run one of the examples but this is throwing me the error below:-

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubywrite/exceptions (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/ankit/Downloads/Studies/PLI/Assignment2/RubyWrite/lib/rubywrite.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from pcc.rb:4:in `require_relative'
    from pcc.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

I am not sure what needed to be done. My Ruby version is :

`- ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]`

My gem env is :-

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.25
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/ankit/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: What are you trying to `require`? One of your own classes/files?

Comment: I am trying to require file from one of the folder rubywrite. The file is exceptions.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'require_relative' and specify the full path of the file you want to include. The problem is that 'require' only looks at files that are in Ruby's library path. See also: [What is the difference between require_relative and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-require-relative-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

The current directory is not included on the library include paths by default.

You may add it explicitly on the Ruby command line using the `-I` option:

```
ruby -I. the_file.rb
```