# How to use lib in rails migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I was wondering if there is a way to easily access methods/classes from the lib folder in migrations? I found a way to require them with

```
require File.expand_path("../../lib/my_library")
```

I don't really like this and I was wondering if there is a more common way to include those libraries required by the migration?

Comment: Ref:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-require-relative-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't find it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rake db:migrate load all rails environment, so you can just add lib in autoload in application.rb file like this and it should work.

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: Just as I thought. I don't unterstand why they don't add it always. I mean, the lib directory is something special isn't it? But thanks for your answer. :)