# Can `require` be replaced by `require_relative`?

Tags: ruby, require

Given that there is `require_relative`, which accepts relative as well as absolute paths, is there any reason to particularly use `require`, which accepts only absolute paths? Can all `require` be replaced by `require_relative`?

**Edit**

Sergio Tulentsev noticed me that `require_relative` cannot be used for gems. Why is it designed so? What problem would arise if `require_relative` were merely a superset of `require` and `require` be deprecated? Or, is it just because `require_relative` appeared later than the incorporation of gems into the Ruby core system, and the author of `require_relative` did not do modification to the code around the gems system?

Comment: `require` can require gems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between require\_relative and require in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-the-difference-between-require-relative-and-require-in-ruby)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require 'json'
```

`require` can be used also to require code from gems and `require_relative` can't do that. Ergo, the latter can not be a replacement for the former.

### RE: edit

I think the answer to your additional question is: code complexity. `require` has additional power to search lib path. `require_relative` substitutes base path and so on. Unifying all features in the same function would probably overcomplicate it. The more complex code is, the more likely it is to have bugs. That's my guess.

Answer (score 2):

> Can all require be replaced by require_relative?

**No**: it's the other way around: `require_relative` is a convenient subset of `require`:

```
require_relative('path')
```

equals:

```
require(File.expand_path('path', File.dirname(__FILE__)))
```

if `__FILE__` is defined, or it raises `LoadError` otherwise.

> is there any reason to particularly use require?

You can only do the following operations with `require` and not `require_relative`:

- requires relative to the **current directory** (not current file): `require './a.rb'`
- uses the search path (`$LOAD_PATH`) to require: `require 'a.rb'`

  This is not possible with `require_relative` because the docs say that path search only happens when "the filename does not resolve to an absolute path" (i.e. starts with `/` or `./` or `../`), which is always the case for `File.expand_path`.

---

I have explained this in more detail at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26565471/895245

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has the `-I` flag for including directories for the purpose of `require` lookup.  So if you either `push` the folder to the `$:` variable (which is to say `ENV['PATH']`) or use the `Isome_lib` at the command line then `require` can be used without specifying the base folder location for that file.

`require_relative` is used for a different purpose, which is to use the `__FILE__` directory location to refer to location for the file you are wanting to `require`.  So it *could* be used to require files from a gem, but it could be more work to do so.  Realizing that gems can be 'vendored' and located in a directory that is very close, or even contained, by your application.  Normally, gems that are installed are placed into the `$PATH` for ease of lookup, so this is not normally needed.

Requiring gems using `require_relative` is an anti-pattern, though, as it should probably be required as a gem in your `Gemfile` where you can specify the source of the file and the environment will be loaded for the application using `Bundler`, perhaps.