# ruby `require': cannot load such file

Tags: ruby

I have a directory tree.

```
- app.rb
- folder/
  -one.rb
```

app.rb

```
 $:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
 require 'folder/one'
```

When I ran `ruby app.rb`, I got this error:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- ./radius/dictionary (LoadError).
```

I don't know why. Please help.

Comment: You are requiring `folder/one` and you get an error about loading `./radius/dictionary`, maybe there is something missing in you example?

Comment: @toro2k I think for simplicity OP gave some conceptual names...according to his/her FS... But forgot to edit the actual error message according to the same.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Probably not, there is no problem with OP code as it is posted, my guess is that the error comes from `one.rb`, but without seeing the file or the complete stack trace is quite hard to tell.

Comment: @toro2k Yes there is a problem... Did you read my answer? OP added the file path for `app.rb`.Not the one for `one.rb`. Accordingly I tested. Either you or me missing something.. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is require\_relative in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-require-relative-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3):

When the location of the file you are loading is relative to the file you are loading it from, use `require_relative`:

```
require_relative 'folder/one'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try only the below:

```
 $:.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/folder')
 require 'one'
```

The above will work.

Your one is not working as,you are adding the directory of the file `app.rb` as `path/to/file`.But `one.rb` is inside the `path/to/file/folder/one.rb`. So you need to add `path/to/file/folder` in `$:`.

Comment: Hi, I tried yours, then I got this error: /Users/min/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- one (LoadError)
 from /Users/min/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
 from test.rb:3:in `<main>'

Comment: If your file system is arranged as per your description,then it should work. Because I have tested the same.