# navigate back a directory in ruby

Tags: ruby, directory

How can I navigate back one or multiple directories in Ruby?

For example:

`users/luigi/test/folder/file.rb`

If I'm in the `folder` directory and want my `file.rb` script to load a file from within the `test` directory, how can I do that?

Something like:

`require /../required_file.rb`

Comment: .. is parent directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`require_relative`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-require-relative-in-ruby)

```
require_relative "../test/file.rb"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require_relative "../requred_file.rb"
```