# Class can't be found

Tags: ruby, sinatra, require

I'm building a project in Ruby using Sinatra in Windows 7.

My project structure is:

```
/project 
  |_ one.rb
  |_ sin.rb
```

So, my code in `one.rb`:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sin'
```

But when I run it, the console puts:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:
36:in `require': cannot load such file -- sin (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custo
m_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from one.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can put the **sin.rb** into the **lib/** folder, then just run:

```
bundle install
```

and then:

```
bundle exec project/one.rb
```

#### Expanded version

Make sure that you properly made the **Gemfile**, and **.gemspec**. The templates for the files can be automatically generated by *bundler* as follows:

```
bundle gem your_gem_name
```

Then you shell create the folders **bin/**, and **lib/**, put **sin.rb** into **lib/**, and **one.rb** into **bin/**. And fill all *TODOs* in the **.gemspec** the with proper values:

```
spec.summary       = %q{short summary}
spec.description   = %q{longer description}
```

Then run bundle install, and exec as it was specified above. And in case if you will generate the gem, and then install it with `gem install`, you'll not need to change anything.

Comment: This should include `./lib` in `$LOAD_PATH`?

Comment: Can you post an example of a "properly made Gemfile" please?

Answer (score 4):

You have to use [`require_relative`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative):

```
require_relative 'sin'
```

Or include the current directory in your [`$LOAD_PATH`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html):

```
$LOAD_PATH << '.'
require 'sin'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `require_relative 'sin'`. It will work. Read the documentation of [`Kernel#require_relative`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative)

Read this post [What is the difference between require_relative and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-require-relative-in-ruby) to know more.