# Making two Ruby classes talk to each other in the same directory

Tags: ruby, include, require

I have two .rb files in the same directory

```
samplecode.rb
otherclass.rb
```

here is the contents of SampleCode

```
require 'otherclass'
include OtherClass

class SampleCode
  #...
end
```

and here is the contents of OtherClass

```
require 'samplecode'

class OtherClass
  #...
end
```

when I run "ruby otherclass.rb" I get the following error:

[image]

I can't figure out what's going wrong, because these two files are definitely in the same directory. What gives?

Comment: You have a lot going wrong here. You should not be including `samplecode` inside `otherclass` AND `otherclass` in `sampleclass` It should be a one way include. This will lead to circular dependencies.

Comment: @JustinWood, to what extent are circular dependencies between Ruby files a problem? Ruby won't load the same file twice.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
require './otherclass'
```

and

```
require './samplecode'
```

require should handle circular references issue but your current dir is probably not in your path.

Answer (score 2):

The `require` method searches for files in Ruby's `$LOAD_PATH`, which doesn't include your current directory for security reasons. So, when you `require 'sample_code'`, it will look all over your system for that file and fail to find it, because it is in your current directory.

You should add the current directory to the search path so that Ruby will find your script:

```
ruby -l . other_class.rb
```

Note that it won't work if you try to run the script from outside the directory where `sample_code.rb` is in. Worse; if a different file with the same name is in the current directory, it will be loaded and executed instead of your script. This is a possible attack vector, and the reason why the current directory is not in the search path.

Answer (score 2):

try this out:

use require_relative when loading the file not present ruby's $LOAD_PATH

[read it for more info on `require` and `require_relative`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-the-difference-between-require-relative-and-require-in-ruby)