# Can't inherit a class defined in separate file - Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

I have a file 'page.rb' containing:

```
require_relative "template.rb"

class MM8 < Template

end
```

I then have a file 'template.rb' containing:

```
class Template

end
```

Why can't I extend the MM8 class with the Template class? I get 'uninitialized constant Template (NameError)' when I try to run the program.

Comment: what exactly is require_relative doing? Is it the equivalent of writing more code on a page, or is it starting a new ruby process, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to call `require_relative` without file extension:

```
require_relative 'template'
```

You can read more about the difference between `require` and `require_relative` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-the-difference-between-require-relative-and-require-in-ruby).

Comment: @ZachSmith Are you sure that `template.rb` and `page.rb` are in the same folder? Because i've just tested your code and it works fine.

Comment: Ah they were, but it is working now. I hadn't saved template.rb with the actual class defined :p. Sorry, thanks for the help