# What does the single period in `require "./file_name.rb"` do?

Tags: ruby

In lines like:

`require "./hello.rb"`

What does the single period do? I know that using 2 periods is going back a directory from current location.

Also, is there a difference in the following:

`require_relative "../file.rb"`

`require "../file.rb"`

Comment: . Is the current directory, basically it's the same as `hello.rb`

Comment: Cool, thank you. Another question: Is  `require "./hello.rb"` the same as using `require_relative "hello.rb"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unixy systems, the dot refers to the current working directory.  The two dots in your second and third examples, refer to the parent of your working directory.

As for `require_relavive` vs `require` see this question: [What is the difference between require_relative and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-the-difference-between-require-relative-and-require-in-ruby)

Short answer: If your ruby script lives in `/scripts/bin/`,  and you run it from `/home/work` :

- `require "./file.rb"` pulls in `/home/work/file.rb`
- `require_relative "./file.rb"` pulls in `/scripts/bin/file.rb`