# Require code of one file into another

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have called my function in gems/plugins/account_reports/lib/account_reports/grade_reports.rb file. Now I want to use the same function in lib/reporting/enrollment_details_progress_report.rb file. For that I added  require '/gems/plugins/account_reports/lib/account_reports/grade_reports' in lib/reporting/enrollment_details_progress_report.rb file at the top and called that function by using AccountReports::GradeReports.fetch_student_course_completion_date(rec["course_id"], rec["term_id"]) but I am getting the error `'undefined method`fetch_student_course_completion_date'' for AccountReports::GradeReports:Class'`.

Also tried load "gems/plugins/account_reports/lib/account_reports/grade_reports.rb" but still I am getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that class have `fetch_student_course_completion_date` as a class method?

you can try `require_relative`. [What is the difference between require_relative and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-the-difference-between-require-relative-and-require-in-ruby)

Comment: I tried require_relative '/gems/plugins/account_reports/lib/account_reports/grade_reports.rb' but still getting the error: cannot load such file -- /gems/plugins/account_reports/lib/account_reports/grade_reports.rb

Comment: @Sneha Ok, use require. And Are you sure, that class have fetch_student_course_completion_date as a class method?

Comment: Added self in fetch_student_course_completion_date method. Its working now. Thanks.

Comment: @Sneha Ok, I like to help ;)