# RubyGems - require, file location and (load error) complications

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require, directory

very new to coding so, having exhausted Google and Stack Overflow, would really appreciate some advice...

I am currently building a web-scraper to get familiar with CMD vs Sublime Text, feeling Ruby in action;  So i am working my way through [this tutorial](https://www.distilled.net/resources/web-scraping-with-ruby-and-nokogiri-for-beginners/)

After having actioned in CMD

```
C:\gem install HTTParty
```

SUBLIME TEXT - starts with this code:

```
require_relative 'HTTParty' 
require_relative 'Nokogiri'
```

etc

But before i can get to anything more from CMD, i hit web_scraper.rb and it returns with:

```
C:/Users/ATH18/Desktop/nokogiri_tutorial/web_scraper.rb:1:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- C:/Users/ATH18/Desktop/nokogiri_tutorial/httparty (LoadError)
from C:/Users/ATH18/Desktop/nokogiri_tutorial/web_scraper.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]

I think this has to be due to one of the following:

i) maybe gems have to have their actual files dragged into whatever folder you're creating a new program in?
ii) i'm missing another piece of information that would let it run properly?
iii) perhaps there's another way to tell CMD/ruby that the "require"d gem is not in the current folder (I read this somewhere but their advice didnt seem to work either).

NOTE - i have done gem install xxxxxx in both the C:\ directory and C:\users\desktop\projectFolder\

Help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `require` instead of `require_relative`. The difference between both a is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672600/92049

---

Use `require 'GEMNAME'` for gems installed with `gem install GEMNAME`; use `require_relative 'PATH'` to require a file relative to the file containing `require_relative`. (Most often you will find yourself using `require`.)

To come back to your question: As it says in the tutorial, you have to write `require 'HTTParty'` instead of `require_relative 'HTTParty'`.

Does this answer your original question?

Comment: Ah okay... have removed the require. But now getting: 

`code` SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) `code`

Comment: @NewbieAid Now that the problem in this question has fixed, it has uncovered a new problem. That new problem should be asked about in a new question.

Comment: Thanks Wayne - solved the issues by adding the gem name into the gem file manually, via Notepad.