# Can't call method from other script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9

Here a screen of my code and error messages I get

[image: Code and error message]

Uninitialized constant CLASS (NameError)

I am using Cloud9, Ruby, Rails server.  I created two simple test scripts.  test.rb and parent.rb

parent.rb has a method 'yes' which displays the word yes...  test is trying to be a child/dependant of parent so that it can access parent's method 'yes'.  But no luck.

I've tried "class test < parent"
I've tried adding "require 'parent'"
I've tried changing parent from class parent to module parent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-the-difference-between-require-relative-and-require-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `require_relative` to make it work

Also, `yes` method in `Parent` class is an instance method and you need to instantiate Parent class in order to user it's instance method.

Your `test.rb` should look like this:

```
require_relative 'parent.rb'

class Test < Parent
  Parent.new.yes
end
```