# How to correctly use require? - ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, require

I have this small project I've been working on. 
In this project, I've been using the rspec to test the classes, so my project folder is structured like this:

```
.
+--lib
|   +-- # bunch of classes 
|
+--spec
|   +-- # bunch of tests
```

Being in the project root, if I run `rspec` all the tests are ran correctly.

However, if I run the main script through the command line, like this: `ruby lib/main.rb`, then I get this error:

```
`require': cannot load such file
```

If I change all the requires to `./lib/class_name` it works, but the `rspec` stops working.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Right, there's no rails tag. In this case, the generic answer would be "Set up your `$LOAD_PATH` so that all needed directories are there". That's how `require` works. It searches for the thing in each directory in your LOAD_PATH

Comment: Maybe you should use [require_relative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-the-difference-between-require-relative-and-require-in-ruby)

Comment: I think the best solution would be similar to what is done here https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb They've simply appended the required paths into `$LOAD_PATH` then 'required' this helper in the tests . As far as I know if you are typing in exact paths, `require_relative` loads the exact same paths as `require`.

Comment: Can you give concrete example which doesn't work? I never  had a problem with this so I can't imagine how it's not working. Also main script should be in project root folder, not in lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I took Sergio Tulentsev advise and setted up the `$LOAD_PATH` and that solved my problem!

To do that I added the following code in the beginning of my main script:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

This code adds the current file directory to the beginning of the `$LOAD_PATH`(which is an array used by the require to mount the required files paths and load them).

In other words, this abled my main script to add `lib` to the `$LOAD_PATH` and fix the requires.