# Appium:Ruby: Load error in the gem

Tags: android, ruby, adb, appium

I am having errors while loading this `require-relative` element. Any ideas how to resolve it?

I have tried searching the android sdk, for the following mentioned in the `require relative`, is there any file that I should be placing to get this work?>

```
require 'appium_lib'
require_relative './libs/adbManager'
require_relative './libs/error_handler'
require_relative './libs/android_manifest_parser'
```

The error:

```
cannot load such file -- /Users/jain/Documents/fslearning-android/Features/Support/libs/adbManager (LoadError)
/Users/jain/Documents/fslearning-android/Features/Support/hooks.rb:2:in `require_relative'
/Users/jain/Documents/fslearning-android/Features/Support/hooks.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:96:in `load_code_file'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:142:in `load_file'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `block in load_files!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `load_files!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:253:in `load_step_definitions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:61:in `run!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:32:in `execute!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cucumber-2.4.0/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/cucumber:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/cucumber:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You requested me for help, but other than the error you published originally I can just give you some general advise since I have no experience with appium itself and the prerequisites are too high to try.

Where did you get the code for the require_relatives you are making ?
I can't find much documentation online. They should refer to gems or ruby files.
In the case of a gem (like `require 'appium_lib'`) you need to meet the prerequisites (iOs only ?, gem installed ? etc), in case of a ruby script file you can check where the file is located in your filesystem and you'd better make use of the fileextension `.rb`.

eg `require_relative './libs/adbManager.rb'`
would be a file that is located in a subfolder libs of your main script called `adbManager.rb`.

If it would be part of appium it would rather be something like

```
require 'appium_lib/adbManager'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I somehow have missed the quote while copying from my IDE to here. Its the same error even with quotes.

Comment: As I see from your answer, that `require_relative` is loading a particular file, I wanted to know, if the files mentioned in the above in `require_relative` are a part of `appium_lib`? Any idea on this?

Comment: I got what are those. Those are just to refer an other file, to call a method from one file to another.

Comment: Feel so embarassed now, to have not known this concept.