# how to distribute a ruby script via homebrew

Tags: ruby, homebrew, optparse, thor, load-path

How can I deploy a simple ruby script via homebrew?

Here's what I tried

Wrote formula in a GitHub repo named `homebrew-foo`

```
# file https://github.com/foo/homebrew-foo/blob/master/foo.rb
class Foo < Formula
  desc "A command line tool"
  url "https://github.com/foo/foo/archive/master.zip"
  version "5.0.1"

  def install
    bin.install "foo"
    lib.install Dir["lib/*"]
  end
end
```

The other repository contains the ruby script. These are the files

```
./foo
./lib/libfile1.rb
```

here's what the script does

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require './lib/libfile1.rb'
puts "came here"
```

The problem is that the `require` fails.

```
$ brew install foo/foo/foo
$ foo
```

results in this error

> /Users/user1/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- ./lib/libfile1.rb (LoadError)
>     from
>   /Users/user1/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`
>   require'     from /usr/local/bin/foo

```
$ which foo
/usr/local/bin/foo
```

I suspect it's because the .rb file is not there at `/usr/local/bin/foo/lib/libfile1.rb`

Any ideas whats the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your script:

The first one is you try to `require` some file relatively to the *current* directory; i.e. the one from which the script is run, *not* the one it’s located in. That issue can be fixed by using [Ruby’s `require_relative`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672600/735926):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative './lib/libfile1.rb'
puts "came here"
```

The second issue is the script assumes the `lib/` directory is located in its directory; which it’s not because your formula installs the script under `<prefix>/bin/` and the library files under `<prefix>/lib/`. Homebrew has a helper for that use-case called [`Pathname#write_exec_script`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/f2c2964cf78368b45ff9357d09c5ebe79c48104b/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb#L397). It lets you install everything you need under one single directory, then create an executable under `bin/` that calls your script.

Your formula now looks like this:

```
class Foo < Formula
  desc "A command line tool"
  url "https://github.com/foo/foo/archive/master.zip"
  version "5.0.1"

  def install
    libexec.install Dir["*"]
    bin.write_exec_script (libexec/"foo")
  end
end
```

It installs everything under `libexec/` (`lib/` is usually reserved for lib files), then add an executable under `bin/` that calls your `libexec/foo` script.

Comment: Is there a way, I put add this foo script in my OS's path during the formula installation so that I can execute it from anywhere ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 you need to add Homebrew’s `bin` directory in your path; all formula’s executables are in it.

Comment: It turns out that using `bin.write_exec_script` symlinks these scripts into the /usr/local/bin. So it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question, actually it's a technique used by someone on the net, basically do something like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
DBMGR_HOME = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(DBMGR_HOME, 'lib'))
require 'dbmgr'
```

And the recipe can be like this:

```
https://github.com/callahanrts/homebrew-dbmgr/blob/master/dbmgr.rb
```