# How to create homebrew formula with only scripts

Tags: homebrew

I want to package up a few shell scripts + support files into a homebrew formula that installs these scripts somewhere on the user `$PATH`. I will serve the formula from my own tap.

Reading through the [formula cookbook](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Formula-Cookbook.md) the examples seem to assume cmake or autotools system in the upstream library. What if my project only consists of a few scripts and  config files? Should I just manually copy those into `#{prefix}/` in the Formula?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two cases here:

#### Standalone Scripts

Install them under `bin` using `bin.install`. You can optionally rename them, e.g. to strip the extension:

```rb
class MyFormula < Formula
  # ...

  def install
    # move 'myscript.sh' under #{prefix}/bin/
    bin.install "myscript.sh"

    # OR move 'myscript.sh' to #{prefix}/bin/mybettername
    bin.install "myscript.sh" => "mybettername"

    # OR move *.sh under bin/
    bin.install Dir["*.sh"]
  end
end
```

#### Scripts with Support Files

This case is tricky because you need to get all the paths right. The simplest way is to install everything under `#{libexec}/` then write `exec` scripts under `#{bin}/`. That’s a very common pattern in Homebrew formulae.

```rb
class MyFormula < Formula
  # ...

  def install
    # Move everything under #{libexec}/
    libexec.install Dir["*"]

    # Then write executables under #{bin}/
    bin.write_exec_script (libexec/"myscript.sh")
  end
end
```

Given a tarball (or a git repo) that contains the following content:

- `script.sh`
- `supportfile.txt`

The above formula will create the following hierarchy:

```
#{prefix}/
  libexec/
    script.sh
    supportfile.txt
  bin/
    script.sh
```

Homebrew creates that `#{prefix}/bin/script.sh` with the following content:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
exec "#{libexec}/script.sh" "$@"
```

This means that your script can expect to have a support file in its own directory while not polluting `bin/` *and* not making any assumption regarding the install path (e.g. you don’t need to use things like `../libexec/supportfile.txt` in your script).

See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45187108/735926) for an example with a Ruby script and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978097/creating-a-homebrew-formula-for-standalone-application/45984549#45984549) for an example with manpages.

Note Homebrew also have other helpers to e.g. not only write an `exec` script but also [set environment variables](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/f2c2964cf78368b45ff9357d09c5ebe79c48104b/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb#L414) or [execute a `.jar`](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/f2c2964cf78368b45ff9357d09c5ebe79c48104b/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb#L436).

Comment: It should be noted that the items in your first shell script example should be either/or, not using all three (install shell script OR install script and rename it in one go, OR install all *.sh files)

Comment: Thanks @JustinHammond; I clarified this.

Comment: Is there anywhere in homebrew's documentation that explains this pattern? Seems very common but it took me a while to find this.

Comment: @wcarhart Unfortunately I don’t see it in the documentation, even in the formula cookbook: https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook.