# Fastlane - Cannot load file by `require` command

Tags: ruby, fastlane

I'm trying to use a remote `Fastfile` using the `import_from_git` command. But in order to not have a mess, created a helper in another file. My problem is that `fastlane` correctly clones the main file, but then can't find a helper file.

Fastfile:

```
import_from_git(
    url: '[URL].git',
    branch: 'refactoring',
    path: 'RSBMatch.rb'
)
```

RSBMatch.rb:

```
require 'helper/match_helper'

fastlane_version "1.47.0"

default_platform :ios

platform :ios do

  lane :test_lane do
    RSB::Test.hey
  end
end
```

match_helper.rb:

```
module RSB
  module Test

    def self.hey
      puts 'Hello'
    end

  end
end
```

Error:

> require': cannot load such file -- helper/match_helper (LoadError)

Comment: what is Fastfile?

Comment: "Fastfile" is the config file of the fastlane tool tagged in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
require_relative 'helper/match_helper'
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3672608/5346899)