# Requiring files from a required file

Tags: ruby, require

I have a file `required.rb` required by other files `main.rb` and `tester.rb`, each of which is invoked separately and run separately.

Within `required.rb`, I want to require all files in a subdirectory of the required file. The whole thing looks something like this:

```
main.rb
lib/
   required.rb
   req_files/
      req1.rb
      req2.rb
      req3.rb
tester/
   tester.rb
```

The code to import the required files looks like:

```
Dir[Dir.pwd + "/req_files/*.rb"].each do  |file|
  require file
end
```

In suggested strategies I have seen, be it utilizing `Dir.pwd` or `__FILE__`, the context applied to `required.rb`'s location is the context of whichever original file required it in the first place, which means that I can't support requiring from both of those files separately with the current setup.

Is there a way to denote a path relative to the actual `required.rb`?

EDIT :

It's not though, because changing require to require_relative doesn't change the fact that `Dir[Dir.pwd + "/req_files/*.rb"]` and more specifically `Dir.pwd` resolves with respect to the original file (main or tester), so it cannot be expressed as is in required and work for both entry points

Also note that `required.rb` is required via `require_relative` already from both `main.rb` and `tester.rb`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between require\_relative and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-the-difference-between-require-relative-and-require-in-ruby)

Comment: @BradWerth: not really a _duplicate_, though. Because this question doesn't mention `require_relative`.

Comment: There were better "duplicates" that made worse targets. I was looking at it sorta like how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it gets used...

Comment: I think the duplicate is justified, as it is clearly the information the OP is seeking. If not this one, I bet I could find at least one more require_relative question in the last 10 years of ruby questions....

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to denote a path relative to the actual required.rb

Yes, kinda. There's another method for this.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative

> **require_relative(string) → true or false**
>
> Ruby tries to load the library named string relative to the requiring file’s path. If the file’s path cannot be determined a LoadError is raised. If a file is loaded true is returned and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrect regarding `__FILE__`; Using `File.dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `Dir.pwd` works for giving the directory of the actual file versus the directory of the invoking file.