# Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant in lib directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails, there is a lib directory. It is not autoloaded by default. So when you load the Rails environment, all the modules and classes in this folder will not be known at runtime. I tried to autoload lib in the `application.rb`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor #{config.root}/lib)
```

But it does not work. It does not load the modules and classes in lib I want loaded.

File structure is as so:

```
\lib
  \docket
    \practice_factory
      factory.rb
      pa_factory.rb
```

I have this in factory.rb:

```
module Docket
  module PracticeFactory
    class Factory
      def self.practice_methods
        descendants.collect {|descendant| descendant.practice_methods }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And in pa_factory.rb:

```
module Docket
  module PracticeFactory
    class PaFactory < Factory
      def self.practice_methods
        {
            some: 'data',
            more: 'stuff'
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I load rails console, and I get empty array when I run:

```
Docket::PracticeFactory::Factory.practice_methods
 => []
```

The reason why array is empty is because the PaFactory is not loaded in memory. This is despite the fact that I included lib to autoload path! So why is not not autoloaded #1?

Also, I added the following to factory.rb:

```
Dir["#{Rails.root}/lib/docket/practice_factory/*_factory.rb"].each {|file| require file }
```

And it gives me error:

> RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant
>   Docket::PracticeFactory::Factory

Interesting error, I am loading files with *_factory.rb and factory.rb does not have an underscore, but those other files do inherit from Factory. How can this error be avoided?

Comment: Note that I deleted my other post about Docket::PracticeFactory.constants(true) not returning any of the classes defined in this Module. That is related to this issue - the fact that autoload_paths does not work and does not load the files in lib directory and therefore Docket::PracticeFactory.constants(true)  does not see the constants because they are not loaded in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have nothing to say about autoloading, the magic never worked for me and I try to avoid it wherever possible.

For the latter, the error cause is clear: you try to load `PbFactory` that requires `Factory` class to be defined (since it derives from it,) and it is not yet defined. To resolve an issue just put your

```
Dir["*_factory.rb"].each {|file| require_relative file }
```

**after** the `Factory` class declaration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-the-difference-between-require-relative-and-require-in-ruby

Comment: So what? I know what is the difference, I just shortened the statement so that it fits the screen.

Comment: I added that link for myself, I did not know the difference between the two.