# Ruby: Require Fails To Import - Need To Set Root Directory

Tags: ruby, windows, path, require

Forgive my inexperience with Ruby, but I am unable to run a script within a third-party project with the following structure:

```
˅ alpha
  ˅ lib
     ˅ bravo
        golf.rb
     ˅ charlie
        ˃ delta
           ˅ echo
              foxtrot.rb
              require "charlie/delta/echo/__init"
              __init.rb
              require "bravo/golf"
```

What should my command-line be to run the script, '**foxtrot.rb**', as the following generates an error:

```
ruby "c:\arby\lib\bravo\charlie\delta\echo\foxtrot.rb"

"'require': cannot load such file -- charlie/delta/echo/__init (LoadError)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the code inside of __init.rb, it won't work.

```
require "charlie/delta/echo/__init"
__init.rb
require "bravo/golf"
```

`require` tells ruby to load the code inside a ruby file.  In order for it to work, the files need to be organized correctly.  You can also use `require_relative` but they still need a relative path from the file calling them.  See [What is the difference between require_relative and require in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672586/what-is-the-difference-between-require-relative-and-require-in-ruby#3672600)

Comment: Yes. Is it possible to set a root directory (here lib) from which the require imports are relatively positioned and, if so, how?

Comment: I can't imagine why anyone would create a script in such a chaotic file structure.  Furthermore, I would surely not execute such a script without knowing what might be hidden in this crazy rats nest.

Comment: Forget the naming convention I used - original project is from an MIT research project - I am not worried about its provenance. Can I set a 'load path' root directory from which all requires are relatively located? Any experience with [Pathological](https://rubygems.org/gems/pathological)?

Comment: I haven't use that gem but give it a shot, though it has not been updated in a long time. If it doesn't work, try a fork which will support newer ruby versions. https://github.com/ooyala/pathological/pull/6